# How to get a JObject from a JArray with weakly typed code using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Data (JArray):

```
[{ provinceid: "1", provincename: "北京", cityid: "33", cityname: "北京", jp: "bj", quanpin: "beijing" },
{ provinceid: "1", provincename: "北京", cityid: "600", cityname: "朝阳(北京)", jp: "cy", quanpin: "chaoyang" },
{ provinceid: "1", provincename: "北京", cityid: "601", cityname: "通州(北京)", jp: "tz", quanpin: "tongzhou" },
{ provinceid: "1", provincename: "北京", cityid: "46", cityname: "昌平", jp: "cp", quanpin: "changping" },
{ provinceid: "1", provincename: "北京", cityid: "602", cityname: "顺义", jp: "sy", quanpin: "shunyi" }]
```

Condition:

`cityname == "北京"`

Desired result (JObject):

```
{ provinceid: "1", provincename: "北京", cityid: "33", cityname: "北京", jp: "bj", quanpin: "beijing" }
```

Question is: how to use the condition to get the result from the data with weakly typed code?

Comment: Can you tell what you have done and what was the failure. Have you used `JObject.Parse(json)`? Please edit the question to add more such information

Comment: Thank you , @BrianRogers ! I will try it

Answer (score 0):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```

...

```
public class City
{
    public int provinceid { get; set; }
    public string provincename { get; set; }
    public int cityid { get; set; }
    public string cityname { get; set; }
}

public void FindCity()
{
    string json = @"[{ provinceid: ""1"", provincename: ""北京"", cityid: ""33"", cityname: ""北京"", jp: ""bj"", quanpin: ""beijing"" }, { provinceid: ""1"", provincename: ""北京"", cityid: ""600"", cityname: ""朝阳(北京)"", jp: ""cy"", quanpin: ""chaoyang"" }, { provinceid: ""1"", provincename: ""北京"", cityid: ""601"", cityname: ""通州(北京)"", jp: ""tz"", quanpin: ""tongzhou"" }, { provinceid: ""1"", provincename: ""北京"", cityid: ""46"", cityname: ""昌平"", jp: ""cp"", quanpin: ""changping"" }, { provinceid: ""1"", provincename: ""北京"", cityid: ""602"", cityname: ""顺义"", jp: ""sy"", quanpin: ""shunyi"" }]";

    List<City> cities = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<City>>(json);
    City 北京 = cities.Where(city => city.cityname == "北京").First();
}
```

Comment: oh, thank you so much , @Jame .
but i don't want to use Strongly Typed code , do you have any idea about no use "Public class City{}" to get the result.